# Using Sumif in SQL Server2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I currently work as a Healthcare Analyst. I have been using Microsoft Access the past couple years for querying and generating reports. My company now wants me to learn, expand my SQL knowledge and use SQL Server2008 daily going forward.

I have made some progress understanding the differences between Access and SQL, but they are still many things I'm unfamiliar with.

I would like some insight on sub queries, and how to use SUMIF in SQL. Below I have pasted step (1) the first part of a SQL sub query I have put together. **Step(2) is the SQL view from Microsoft Access** that I want to translate into SQL, but some insight is needed on the proper syntax for a SUMIF statement.

Any insight is greatly appreciated...

**Step (1) SQL Server 2008:**

```
SELECT
    [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID
,   OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS
,   [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER
,   [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD
,   OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN
,   REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE, 101), '/', '') AS ENTRY_DATE
,   SUM(ENTRY_AMOUNT) AS ENTRY_AMOUNT
FROM
    OUTPAT_REGISTER
    LEFT JOIN 
        OUTPAT_BILL_REF
        ON 
        (
            OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER
        )
            AND (OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.REGISTRATION_CD)
    LEFT JOIN 
        OUTPAT_ACCT_REC
        ON 
        (
            OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.PATIENT_NUMBER
        )
            AND (OUTPAT_BILL_REF.BILL_REFERENCE = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.REFERENCE_NUM)
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                CLINIC_ID
            ,   PATIENT_NUMBER
            ,   REGISTRATION_CD
            FROM
                OP_VISIT_HISTRY
            GROUP BY
                CLINIC_ID
            ,   PATIENT_NUMBER
            ,   REGISTRATION_CD
            --ORDER BY CLINIC_ID
        ) AS [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID]
        ON 
        (
            OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER
        )
            AND (OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD = [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD)
GROUP BY
    [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID
,   OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS
,   [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER
,   [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD
,   OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE
,   OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN
HAVING
    OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE > '12/31/2010'
```

**Step(2)From Access in SQL View:**

```
SELECT [Non Recurring Clinic Step1].CLINIC_ID, dbo_HR_FINAN_CLASS.SUMMARY_CATGRY, [TABLE LAYOUT].ENTRY_TYPE, 
Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #12/1/2012# And #12/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Dec'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #11/1/2012# And #11/30/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Nov'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #10/1/2012# And #10/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Oct'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #9/1/2012# And #9/30/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Sept'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #8/1/2012# And #8/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Aug'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #7/1/2012# And #7/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Jul'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #6/1/2012# And #6/30/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Jun'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #5/1/2012# And #5/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [May'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #4/1/2012# And #4/30/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Apr'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #3/1/2012# And #3/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Mar'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #2/1/2012# And #2/29/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Feb'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #1/1/2012# And #1/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Jan'12], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #12/1/2011# And #12/31/2011#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS [Dec'11], Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #1/1/2012# And #12/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS 2012YTD, Sum(IIf([entry_date] Between #1/1/2011# And #12/31/2011#,[sumofentry_amount],0)) AS 2011YTD
FROM [TABLE LAYOUT] INNER JOIN ([Non Recurring Clinic Step1] INNER JOIN ((dbo_OUTPAT_REGISTER INNER JOIN dbo_HR_FINAN_CLASS ON dbo_OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN = dbo_HR_FINAN_CLASS.FINAN_CLASS_CD) INNER JOIN dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS ON dbo_OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTER_AREA = dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REGISTER_AREA) ON ([Non Recurring Clinic Step1].REGISTRATION_CD = dbo_OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD) AND ([Non Recurring Clinic Step1].PATIENT_NUMBER = dbo_OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER)) ON [TABLE LAYOUT].ENTRY_CLASS = [Non Recurring Clinic Step1].CHARGE_CLASS
WHERE (((dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE)<>"RE"))
GROUP BY [Non Recurring Clinic Step1].CLINIC_ID, dbo_HR_FINAN_CLASS.SUMMARY_CATGRY, [TABLE LAYOUT].ENTRY_TYPE
ORDER BY [Non Recurring Clinic Step1].CLINIC_ID;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`SUM(IIF())` is the equivalent of using an aggregate  with a `CASE` expression:

```
sum(case 
        when [entry_date] >= '2012-12-01' and [entry_date] <= '2012-12-31' 
        then [sumofentry_amount] 
        else 0 
    end) AS [Dec'12]
```

Then you will just repeat this as needed for your other columns.

The `CASE` and the aggregate function are pivoting the data from the row values into columns.  In SQL Server 2005+ you can implement the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function, but you can also use something similar to below:

```
select CLINIC_ID,
    SUMMARY_CATGRY,
    ENTRY_TYPE,
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 12 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Dec12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 11 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Nov12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 10 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Oct12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 9 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Sep12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 8 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Aug12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 7 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jul12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 6 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jun12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 5 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [May12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 4 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Apr12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 3 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Mar12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 2 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Feb12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 1 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jan12],
    SUM(case when EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2012YTD],
    SUM(case when EntryYear = 2011 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2011YTD]
from
(
    SELECT [Non Recurring Clinic Step1].CLINIC_ID, 
        dbo_HR_FINAN_CLASS.SUMMARY_CATGRY, 
        [TABLE LAYOUT].ENTRY_TYPE, 
        datepart(month,[entry_date]) EntryMonth,
        datepart(year,[entry_date]) EntryYear,
        [sumofentry_amount],
    FROM <yourtables and joins go here>
    WHERE dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE)<>'RE'
        and datepart(year,[entry_date]) in (2011, 2012)
) src
group by CLINIC_ID, SUMMARY_CATGRY, ENTRY_TYPE
```

Comment: correct, but OP'S endgame is to break out the report by months so she should use GROUP BY datepart(month,entry_date)

Comment: Right but they have it as columns so eventually the data will have to be pivoted.

Comment: @blueefeet correct, she can pivot on the result set latter using the group by will make the code more maintainable.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply bluefeet. I see were you are going with the example above. gh9, thank you also for your input. Not sure what's going on with my user name because you referred to me as she.lol. I'm a male, my name is Brice.

Comment: @user2026836 without seeing the whole picture it is sort of like guesswork but you are pivoting the data into columns. There are many ways to perform this task. You can search this site for the tag pivot and you will find lots of examples. :)

Comment: Thank you guys. Learning SQL has been a bit of a challenge, but I will keeping reading and asking questions to get better at it.

Comment: @user2026836 Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow.  Keep in mind that if any answers to your questions are helpful, then you should consider accepting it via the checkmark to the left of the answer.  It helps future visitors to the site with similar questions and you will earn site rep by accepting. :)

Comment: Bluefeet, I got the following message after using your syntax:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 58
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @user2026836 you have an extra comma in your subquery at the end of this line `EntryYear, [sumofentry_amount]` <-- there is a comma here

Comment: Fixed it, now I have:  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 63
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'On'.

Comment: @user2026836 you are missing the table names that you want to join on. You just have `Inner Join On([Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1]` but no table name.  The table must be listed on each join

Comment: Ok, I will look through the code again thoroughly for my missing pieces and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Bluefeet, I inserted the inner joins and now have the below message:Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 76
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Comment: @user2026836 without having access to your full query, I would be guessing at to what the issue is.  I can suggest that you format the query, make sure you have aliases on all subqueries.

Comment: Ok, will do. Where can post my updated query syntax so you could maybe point me in the right direction? Should I edit the original posting and paste the new syntax there?

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question

Comment: For the sake of brevity, you should replace the `CASE` statement with `IIF` function.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik `IIF` didn't become available until SQL Server 2012. Considering this was tagged with SQL Server 2008, that wouldn't work.  Also, I prefer to use syntax that could potentially be used on all database engines - and they support `CASE`

Comment: @bluefeet: fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use the IIf([entry_date] Between #12/1/2012# And #12/31/2012#,[sumofentry_amount],0).

put the entry_date between timeA and Timeb in your where clause and just sum the sumofentry_amount. for example

remove the entire sum(...........) statement
and put another group by datepart(month,entry_date)

so your query will look like

```
YOUR SELECT STATEMENT
YOUR FROM STATEMENT
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH,ENTRY_DATE)-- USING THIS WILL SPLIT IT OUT INTO THE MONTHS YOU NEED

CREATE TABLE foo(
amount int null
,targetDate datetime null
)
INSERT INTO FOO (amount,targetDate) values(14,'01/01/2012')
INSERT INTO FOO (amount,targetDate) values(16,'01/01/2012')
INSERT INTO FOO (amount,targetDate) values(30,'02/01/2012')
INSERT INTO FOO (amount,targetDate) values(15,'02/01/2012')
INSERT INTO FOO (amount,targetDate) values(80,'03/01/2012')
INSERT INTO FOO (amount,targetDate) values(80,'04/01/2012')
INSERT INTO FOO (amount,targetDate) values(6,'03/01/2012')

Select sum(amount)
from foo
group by DATEPART(month, targetDate)
```

results set
30     1
45     2
86     3
80     4

Comment: gh9, I don't completely understand your above. Wouldn't I have to enter in some sort of date syntax such as 12/01/2012? I'm not familiar with DATEPART. If possible can you show an example with my data pasted?  thanks